# Trying to move A page to another path in AEM through java code

Tags: java, adobe, aem

So I am trying to change the path of my "demomovement" page to archive-articles. But somewhere its crashing. Can anyone please help me out here?

```
@Override
public void run() {

        String rs="/content/enablementCapstone/us-capstone/en/article/demomovement";
        Page page = resourceResolver.getResource(rs).adaptTo(Page.class);
        PageManager pm = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);
        String TargetPage="/content/enablementCapstone/us-capstone/en/archive-articles";
        try{
        pm.move(page, TargetPage, null, false, true, null);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            LOG.info("ErrorInMovement");
        }
   LOG.info("\n ====> RUN METHOD !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!S");
}
```

Comment: What exception is throwing? Which version of AEM ddo you use? Wich Service pack is installed?

Comment: What is the error itself?